# Azure App Service Didnt Restart After Microsoft File Server Upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Last Thursday (23rd January) our Azure App Service went down (all deployment slots)

Using the "Diagnose and solve problems" debug feature and drilling down into it I discovered this error".

```
Platform(File Server Upgrade) Your application was recycled due to a file server upgrade. This event occurred multiple times during the day across multiple instances. These events cause a Storage Volume movement which may result in a restart of your application. If this restart event negatively impacts the availability of the application, enabling the Local Cache feature can help reduce dependency on storage file servers to some extent. Learn more: Check Local Cache described in the Troubleshooting and Next Steps.
```

As we don't use the file system much and all deployment slots didn't restart I am not convinced that this is the issue. We had to reboot each individual deployment slot to get them to come back up.

Has anyone else experienced something similar and did using the "Local Cache feature" actually resolve it? This is the first time in over 24 months our site has been down due to an unscheduled event.

Thanks.

Comment: There is similar question here https://serverfault.com/questions/992726/catastrophic-azure-app-service-outage-after-an-automatic-azure-platform-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to reiterate that the deployment of your app uses the file system. When you create an app service, the underlying file system is [mounted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture#file-servers) to a storage volume.

To answer your question, using Local Cache can help mitigate when the underlying volume is undergoing maintenance because your app will copy the `/site` and `/siteextensions` contents to the VM instance upon start up. Once copied, the VM will point to it's "personal copy" of contents. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache for more information.

Hope this helps and let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan this is what we ended up doing.