# Azure Platform(File Server Upgrade) causing my web app to restart

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Over last few days I have noticed that my webapp automatically restarts. I used the Diagnonstics and Solve Errors blade to see what is the cause of the problem.

Then under the webapp restarted section I see that my app restarted due to `Platform(File Server Upgrade)` and the description is `On Instance RD281978FA5321, your application was recycled due to a file server upgrade`.

Is this something Microsoft doing or am the cause of this somehow? thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment of your app uses the file system. When you create an app service, the underlying file system is [mounted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture#file-servers) to a storage volume.

Using **Local Cache** can help mitigate when the underlying volume is undergoing maintenance because your app will copy the `/site` and `/siteextensions` contents to the VM instance upon start up. Once copied, the VM will point to it's "personal copy" of contents. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache for more information.

See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924942/azure-app-service-didnt-restart-after-microsoft-file-server-upgrade) for more details.

Comment: @wallezi, thankyou for your reply. So this started to happen recently. Now, I saw some of the articles above before posting here. However, my question still remains. You see, your second paragraph refers to " the underlying volume is undergoing maintenance". Does this mean it is because Microsoft doing some sort of upgrade? if so that means this will probably stop happening sometimes soon. I have been running my webapp for about 3 years and this is the first time I see this happen. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, when underlying volume is undergoing maintenance, Microsoft VM triggers this action.